# AWS rest api with blank Lambda - First response too slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, rest, aws-lambda, httpresponse

When API Gateway calls a blank Lambda function, the first response time is 1500ms.

The following response time is 150ms.

Is that normal or is something is wrong?

Comment: You might enjoy reading this series of articles, which explains the operation of the AWS Lambda service: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Lambda [cold start](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/) which is normal/expected behaviuor. There are various ways you can improve the cold start

- Try with a larger memory allocation (note that Lambda cost is proportional to memory and cpu)
- Try [provisioned concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html)